# Default settings page for Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a default settings page for Monaco editor which can be shown to the user so she could change her basic preferences? (e.g., toggling the mini-map)

Of course, it's possible to build a custom UI and update the editor from there, but wondering if there's a default page that's already built which we can reuse?

Comment: Tried looking for default page but couldn't find one. Instead you can add a shortcut which will just enable or disable the minimap.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing like a settings page for Monaco. You have to create your own one.